# Linq query to filter multi level classes

Tags: c#, linq

I have my departments data coming from the database. I want to filter this data based on certain criteria.

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":10,
      "Name":"Name 10",
      "Teachers":[  
         {  
            "TeacherId":100,
            "TeacherName":null,
            "DepartmentId":100,
            "Students":[  
               {  
                  "StudentId":1001,
                  "StudentName":null,
                  "TeacherId":10,
                  "DepartmentId":100
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "TeacherId":101,
            "TeacherName":null,
            "DepartmentId":100,
            "Students":[  
               {  
                  "StudentId":1001,
                  "StudentName":null,
                  "TeacherId":10,
                  "DepartmentId":100
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Id":100,
      "Name":"Name 10",
      "Teachers":[  
         {  
            "TeacherId":0,
            "TeacherName":null,
            "DepartmentId":100,
            "Students":[  
               {  
                  "StudentId":5000,
                  "StudentName":null,
                  "TeacherId":50,
                  "DepartmentId":100
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Id":50,
      "Name":"Name 10",
      "Teachers":[  
         {  
            "TeacherId":0,
            "TeacherName":null,
            "DepartmentId":100,
            "Students":[  
               {  
                  "StudentId":2000,
                  "StudentName":null,
                  "TeacherId":50,
                  "DepartmentId":100
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Now I have to filter the departments based on some values as shown below

```
var departmenIds = new List<int>() { 10, 20, 30 };
var teachers = new List<int>() { 100, 200, 300 };
var students = new List<int>() { 1000, 2000, 3000 };
```

I am looking for a query that will return the data in a following fashion

If all department ids exists in the json it will return entire data. If a department with a particular teacher is in the list then only return that teacher and the department. like wise for the student.

I tried this to test if it atleast work at the second level but I am getting all the teachers

```
var list = allDeplrtments.Where(d => d.Teachers.Any(t => teachers.Contains(t.TeacherId))).ToList();
```

Comment: Just checking, but is your data consistent? For example, all the teachers seem to be apart of department 100.

Comment: I dont see any departments with 10, 20, 30 ids in the JSON.

Answer (score 2):

```cs
var list = allDepartments
    .Where(d => departmentIds.Contains(d.Id))
    .Select(d => new Department() {
        Id = d.Id,
        Name = d.Name,
        Teachers = (d.Teachers.Any(t => teacherIds.Contains(t.TeacherId))
            ? d.Teachers.Where(t => teacherIds.Contains(t.TeacherId))
            : d.Teachers)
                .Select(t => new Teacher() {
                    TeacherId = t.TeacherId,
                    TeacherName = t.TeacherName,
                    DepartmentId = d.Id,
                    Students = t.Students.Any(s => studentIds.Contains(s.StudentId))
                        ? t.Students.Where(s => studentIds.Contains(s.StudentId))
                        : t.Students
                })
    })
```

Would something like this work for you?

Comment: Thanks that should work. I used to write this kind of a select to filter the 2nd level class. Do we need to manually enter each and every property for subclasses? I know that this makes sense for a class with less properties but what if i have 40 to 50 properties in each class

Comment: Yeah I think the main issue here is the logic of the filter. Basically, you have a disjunction when you say "or return all teachers/students if no ids are in the list", and you need to handle it either with an if/else or with some LINQ shenanigans that I might not be aware of